# Bluetooth communications with C

Tags: c, bluetooth

I want to write 2 programs with C , one work on Robot1, the other work on Robot2.

So I want the program to send a signal from Robot1 via Bluetooth to Robot2 and Robot2 handles and accepts this signal (message)and reply to Robot1.
how to code this?

please I need any kind of help.

API OF my Robots:

```
/* function for serial communication */
void SerWrite(unsigned char *data,unsigned char length)
{
unsigned char i = 0;
UCSRB = 0x08; // enable transmitter
while (length > 0) {
    if (UCSRA & 0x20) { // wait for empty transmit buffer
        UDR = data[i++];
        length --;
    }
}
while (!(UCSRA & 0x40)); 
for (i = 0; i < 0xFE; i++)
    for(length = 0; length < 0xFE; length++); 
}

void SerRead(unsigned char *data, unsigned char length,unsigned int timeout)
{
unsigned char i = 0;
unsigned int  time = 0;
UCSRB = 0x10; // enable receiver
/* non blocking */
if (timeout != 0) {
    while (i < length && time++ < timeout) {
        if (UCSRA & 0x80) {
            data[i++] = UDR;
            time = 0;
        }
    }
    if (time > timeout) data[0] = 'T';
}
/* blocking */
else {
    while (i < length) {
        if (UCSRA & 0x80) 
            data[i++] = UDR;
    }
}   
}
```

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Bluetooth Model...code...

```
#include "asuro.h"

void Sekunden(unsigned int s)       //Unterprogramm für Sekundenschleife (maximal 65s)
    {
    unsigned int t;                 // Definierung t als Vorzeichenloses int
    for(t=0;t<s*1000;t++)           // 1000*s durchlaufen
        {
        Sleep(72);                  // = 1ms
        }
    }

int main (void)
{
unsigned char daten[2], merker=0;   //Speicher bereitstellen, merker für start/stop
Init();
UBRRL = 0x67;   //4800bps @ 8MHz
Marke:                              // Endlosschleife
SerRead(daten,1,0);                 // Daten einlesen
switch (daten[0])                   //und verarbeiten
{
    case 0x38:  MotorDir(FWD,FWD);  // Vorwärts
                MotorSpeed(merker*120,merker*120);
                SerWrite("Vor                 \r",22);
                break;
    case 0x36:  MotorDir(FWD,FWD);  // Links
                MotorSpeed(merker*120,merker*170);
                SerWrite("Links               \r",22);
                break;
    case 0x37:  MotorDir(RWD,RWD);  // Rückwärts
                MotorSpeed(merker*120,merker*120);
                SerWrite("Zurueck             \r",22);
                break;
    case 0x34:  MotorDir(FWD,FWD);  // Rechts
                MotorSpeed(merker*170,merker*120);
                SerWrite("Rechts              \r",22);
                break;
    case 0x35:  if(merker==1)
                {
                MotorDir(FREE,FREE);// Stop
                MotorSpeed(0,0);
                SerWrite("Stop                \r",22);
                merker=0;
                break;
                }
                else
                {
                MotorDir(FWD,FWD);// Start
                MotorSpeed(120,120);
                SerWrite("Start                \r",22);
                merker=1;
                break;
                }

}
```

---

i want to run this programm on my Robot.

Comment: do you know you can set a bluetooth interface to act as a serial port?

Comment: No dear..I don't have so much idea about this.....But I have an API of my Both Robots.

Comment: @sunny: So you want code that uses an API we don't know anything about?

Comment: @thejh:sorry dear..I forget to add API.......bUT NOW i edited.Please check and let me know.Thanks...

Comment: Oh look, its this thread again.

Comment: @Justsid:Dear I do not know how to programm in C ,So i am asking this question and you are making fun of it...?>

Comment: @sunny, we're not making fun of it, we're just saying you asked this question 3 times always with a different approach, and that was quite funny.

Comment: @klez:ya i agree with you....but still I did not get the answer................

Comment: @sunny, that's because you're not asking the right question :-)

Comment: @klez:I have two (asuro)robot...and I need a programm (in C) ...so that both robot can communicate with each other....via Bluetooth.

Comment: @sunny You need to tell us about your setup. Do you want to run this program on .. a robot ? If so, tell us where the SDK for said robot is so we can look in the documentation There is no standard for bluetooh comunication, and there are litterally thousands different robots around, se we can only make wild guesses as to how to use any bluetooth api your robot might have. If you want to run your C code on a PC, tell us which operating system you're using, and the protocol you're using to talk to your robot.

Comment: @nos:Yes i want to run this programm on my Robot.Here is the link of asuro robot  kit(http://www.arexx.com/downloads/asuro/asuro_manual_en.pdf) please read 9.2.8 amd 9.2.9(API of robot)

Comment: @sunny edit your post to include this information. Are you sure your robot has bluetooth support ? The docs does not even mention it.

Comment: @nos:Yes....My robots supporting bluetooth.

Comment: @sunny It's practically impossible for us, or anyone to program your robot to communicate using bluetooth if there are no documentation for it. The documentation you linked has no information whatsoever about bluetooth, it only covers serial(and imlicittly the IR-serial interface)

Comment: @nos:Right now i do not have bluetooth documentation....but i will provide you...within few days.Thanks for helping......once i will get the documentation ..i will ping you....

Comment: @nos:I have edited the Bluetooth model code.....plz check......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bluetooth communications in C Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271704/bluetooth-communications-in-c-language)

Comment: @abelenky:I posted on 21st november and that question is posted on 24th november.

Comment: @sunny:  a time-difference does not mean the questions are not duplicates of each other.  Do you want to explain why you and another user asked identical questions? Is this homework related?

Comment: @abelenky:How can i know.....................u should ask that user.........why he posted the same question....If you know my question answer then plz.....give me the answer

Answer (score 0):

Robot 2 needs to call `SerRead` with, lets say, a pointer to an empty buffer (length one or so), length one and zero as timeout. Afterwards, let it call `SerWrite` with a pointer to your buffer and length one.

Robot 1 should first call `SerWrite` with one byte of data and then wait for the result of a call to `SerRead`.